# MySQL: Multiple rows to multiple fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this table:

```
userid | property
1 | propA
1 | propC
2 | propA
2 | propB
```

And need this output for an csv export/import

```
userid;propA;propB;probC
1;yes;no;yes
2;yes;yes;no
```

Is that possible without any script language like php? 
It would be totally okay for me if "yes" and "no" are just "1" and "0" (e.g.) but it is important that I need just one row for each user and one field for each property.

Comment: It is possible if all the properties are known when you write the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  However, your format is not CSV (hint:  the "C" means comma).

To get that format, you can do:

```
select t.userid,
       max(case when t.property = 'propA' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as PropA,
       max(case when t.property = 'propB' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as PropB,
       max(case when t.property = 'propC' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as PropC
from table t
group by t.userid;
```

This happens to work because "Yes" is later in the alphabet than "No".  Personally, I would just use numbers, 0 and 1:

```
select t.userid,
       max(t.property = 'propA') as PropA,
       max(t.property = 'propB') as PropB,
       max(t.property = 'propC') as PropC
from table t
group by t.userid;
```

Comment: You can always use `min` instead of `max` in the case that "yes" is before "no" in the alphabet :)